# Problem with evaluation of NA in nested ifelse statements

Tags: r

The order of a nested ifelse statement seems to affect evaluation of is.na conditions.

```
# Create df
Var1 <- c(5,5,5,5)
Var2 <- c(0,0,NA,NA)
tmp.1 <- data.frame(Var1, Var2)


# Why is it not possible to evaluate NA in the second nested ifelse statement?
tmp.1$Var2 <- ifelse(tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & tmp.1$Var2 == 0, 6,
                     ifelse(tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & is.na(tmp.1$Var2), 7, tmp.1$Var2))


# Yet it works when the same ifelse statement comes first.
tmp.1$Var2 <- ifelse(tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & is.na(tmp.1$Var2), 7,
                     ifelse(tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & tmp.1$Var2 == 0, 6, tmp.1$Var2))
```

Is there any logic here or is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First ifelse is evaluated first.
The result of the line below is

```
tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & tmp.1$Var2 == 0 
[1] TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
```

ifelse returns NA instead of FALSE so it doesn't go to the next statment

Comment: This behaviour seems undesirable to me, given that there are further ifelse statements to be run, which are able to evaluate the data and deal with NAs. A smarter ifelse statement might know it is in a nested structure and then look ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can check the `NA` value in the first `ifelse`, so only one `ifelse` is needed, i.e.,

```
tmp.1$Var2 <- ifelse(is.na(tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & tmp.1$Var2 == 0), 7, 6)
```

such that

```
> tmp.1
  Var1 Var2
1    5    6
2    5    6
3    5    7
4    5    7
```

The problem you encountered is that `&` runs over `NA`, since `TRUE & NA` gives `NA`

Comment: I need to use nested ifelse as I have more conditions in reality. It seems the only way to get TRUE & NA (i.e. tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & is.na(tmp.1$Var2)) to evaluate to TRUE would be to convert all NA's to something else, e.g. a number, or to write a true.na function!?

Comment: @pudspop yes, you can do either way as you said, since NA is not "straightforward" when it's in the condition

Comment: To correct myself, a true.na function isn't needed, the problem is when tmp.1$Var1 == 5 & tmp.1$Var2 == 0 is evaluated to NA in the first ifelse statement instead of FALSE, causing it to skip the next ifelse statement. You have to convert all NAs to something else.